# How to get Time from sql3 database and convert to LocalTime

Tags: java

I've got this code but it error every time I get to `rs.getTime("startTime").toLocalTime()`

```
public int loadAttractionsFromDB(String dbName){
        int counter = 0;
        Connection c = null;
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbName);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            String q = "select attName, startTime, endTime, duration from Attractions where park == 1";
            System.out.println(q);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( q );
            while ( rs.next() ) 
            {
                addAttraction(new Attraction(rs.getString("attName"), rs.getTime("startTime").toLocalTime(),rs.getTime("endTime").toLocalTime(), rs.getInt("duration")));
                counter++;
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        {
            System.err.println( "ERROR : "+ e.getMessage() );
        }
        return counter;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an instance of `java.sql.Time`, which is returned by `ResultSet.getTime(...)` to an instance of `LocalTime`, then do this

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.from(rs.getTime("startTime").toInstant());
```

instead of

```
LocalTime localTime = rs.getTime("startTime").toLocalTime();
```

because there seems no method `java.sql.Time.toLocalTime()` in all the Java versions, [at least in version 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html), there is no such method.

Comment: its still give an error: Error parsing time
i am using version 8

Comment: @emvee Could you please add the error message(s) to your question and tell us exactly which data type (SQL) the column has in the database?

Comment: its a sqlLite database and the type is Time

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time this is the full error

Comment: @emvee Then please add the full stack trace of the `SQLException`, please... It seems there is a problem getting the value from the database but not in the part that tries to convert from `java.sql.TIme` to `java.time.LocalTime`.

Answer (score 0):

the output of a Time variable from sql is a String.
so you have to use `rs.getString("startTime")` and then parse it to a LocalTime `LocalTime.parse(rs.getString("startTime"))`